# Implementing an algebraic equation in Base R

Tags: r, function, math, algebra

I'm new to algebraic equations in R and am trying to implement the following equation in R (below).

However, as precise as I have tried to be, I expect the answer to be `0.050865` but instead I get `11.43653`.

I wonder what I am missing as I really can't find any mistakes?

```
delta_T=0.1522
n=18
NT=324
NC=162
p=0.264
N=NT+NC

V_T2 =  ((NT+NC)/(NT*NC))*(1 + ((n - 1)*p)) +
    ( delta_T^2 * ( 
      (((N - 2)*(1-p)^2 ) + (n*(N - 2*n)*p^2) +
         (2* (N - 2*n) * p * (1 - p)) ) /
         (2* (N-2)) * ( (N-2) - (2* (n-1)*p) ) 
    )  )

V_T2

# > [1] 11.43653 BUT I expect the answer to be 0.050865
```

[image]

Comment: Hell is parens and hierarchy of execution, your estimate is correct, and excellent to do prior to a thicket of parens, `(NT + NC) / (NT * NC) `[1] 0.009259259, `(NT + NC) / (NT * NC)*(1 + (n -1)*p) `[1] 0.05081481, `(N-2)*(1-p)^2 + n*(N-2*n)*p^2 + 2*(N - 2*n)*p*(1-p)`
[1] 1001.592, divided by `(2 * (N -2))*((N-2)- 2*(n-1)*p) `[1] 459823.2, `delta_T^2*(1001.592/459823.2)` [1] 5.045791e-05, `(NT + NC) / (NT * NC)*(1 + (n -1)*p) + delta_T^2*(1001.592/459823.2)`
[1] 0.05086527 - my first try at this, before chopping into parts was this [1] 2222.64. So, clearly care required, after estimating.

Comment: Wandering off the path, one might look at `NT + NC / NT * NC ` [1] 405. My parens told me it would come to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the wrong answer is because, in the second term, you think you're doing

```
numerator 
/
denominator
```

but what you're actually doing is

```
numerator 
/
(2 * (N - 2)) 
* 
((N - 2) - (2 * (n - 1) * p) )
```

So, in other words, you were missing parentheses around the denominator.

But, in general, it's helpful to break your code down into intermediate variables, when dealing with complicated equations, so it's easier to debug, and you can do sanity checks on them:

```
equation <- function(NT, NC, n, p, delta_T) {
    N <- NT + NC
    first_term <- N / (NT * NC) * (1 + ((n - 1) * p))
    numerator <- (N - 2) * (1 - p)^2 + n * (N - 2 * n) * p^2 +
         2 * (N - 2 * n) * p * (1 - p)
    denominator <- 2 * (N-2) * (N - 2 - 2 * (n - 1) * p) 
    second_term <- delta_T^2 * (numerator / denominator)
    first_term + second_term
}
```